# d3 mouseover two things at once

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseover, tipsy

I have a line chart and would like to highlight line on mouseover and show tipsy created tooltip as well.

I can get each one to work individually but it is combining the two.

Mouseover line event triggers change in line thickness and colour.

Mouseover hidden circles event triggers tooltip to appear.

But I want them both to happen at the same time and this is not working. It either picks up on mouseover of line or on mouseover of circle but not both.

Is there anyway to solve this? Does it help to give both elements the same z-index?

Here are the most relevant bits of the code >

```
variant.append("path")
 .attr("class", "line")
 .attr("d", function(d) {return line(d.values);})
 .style("stroke", "lightgrey")
 .on("mouseover", function (d,i) {d3.select(this).style("stroke","black").style("stroke-width", "4.5px").style("opacity","1.0")})
 .on("mouseout", function (d,i) {d3.select(this).style("stroke","lightgrey").style("stroke-width", "3.5px").style("opacity","0.55")})

 variant.selectAll("circle")
    .data(function (d) {return (d.values);})
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "tipcircle")
    .attr("cx", function(d,i){return x(d.date)})
    .attr("cy", function(d,i){return y(d.popvar)})
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .attr("title", maketip);

$('circle').tipsy({opacity:0.9, gravity: 'n', html:true});
```

Any advice very welcome.

Thanks

Dan

Comment: You can't have mouseover events for two elements at once, but you could trigger both actions from the mouseover of one element. So in the mouseover handler for the circle you could highlight the `path` element.

Comment: Thanks Lars. I will try that. I thought perhaps I would need to create groups containing the set of circles and the corresponding path. I have the feeling that they way I have coded it now, it may not be easy to pick up which "path" to highlight when hovering over a certain circle. (hope this makes sense)

Comment: Yes, you could use groups as well if that makes sense for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, Lars. Really appreciated. I will be trying out various options today.

Comment: I just appended both the lines and the dots to one single group and triggered both effects on mouseover of the group. This worked very well. Thanks for your help Lars.